# How to fix the "Snap tolerance" error message in QGis?

Tags: qgis, snapping

I am trying to use the "Delete part" tool on a shapefile. While I am starting to use it, an error message shows up : "Could not snap segment. Have you set the tolerance in Settings > Project Properties > General?". I tried to set different tolerances in the snapping options, the error still shows up and I can't delete any part of my polygon.
How to fix that?

I use QGis 1.8.0-Lisboa and Windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: what snapping units have you set?are they set in map units or pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks. I fixed my problem. I had set the snapping unit in map units, I found the right setting for my shapefile in pixels.